# React Quill images uploaded are pixelated

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native-firebase, quill, react-quill

**What's happening:** I'm using react-quill as a text editor and it works well, except when I upload an image via my backend, it renders blurry/pixelated on my frontend.

**Expected:** Renders with equal quality from backend to frontend.

**The following are my results:**

[image: backend]

[image: frontend]

Firebase saves the image as a huuuuuge base 64 number -- over 70k characters.

Does anyone know how to handle this?

**Edit**: Something I thought of is maybe a custom upload button that would first save the image to firebase storage then replace that base64 string with the path to that image in firebase storage?

**Edit2:** I'm saving the state of the editor to give to firebase via the backend with `content: this.state.editorHtml` and do a `database.ref().child('articles').set(data)`. I then render it on the frontend with `data.get('content)`

**Edit3:** I'm rendering the images to the frontend with `import HTMLView from 'react-native-htmlview'` in a tag `<HTMLView value: {data.get('content')} />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of research and aimless debugging, it was *not* the `react-quill` giving me issues by saving the image as a huge base64 string. It was actually the `react-native-htmlview` package that first sets the image props with a `height=10` and `width=10` by default if the props are not set ahead of time in the htmlToElement.js file. By giving the image a width and height before rendering, it solved my blurriness! Hopefully this helps someone else!